# cdf of Binomial distribution

Tags: distribution, cdf

I need your help to solve my problems. cdf of binomial distribution is defined by: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)

```
                     https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zkNV.png
```

So, my problem is:I try to express Ip(k+1,n-k) as below:

```
                        http://i.imgur.com/leKAD4B.png
```

I don't know that formula is true or not true? 
and my second problem is: Ip ( k+1,n-k) = 1 - I1-p(n-k, k+1) is true or not true. If true,I need your hints to proof that formula.

Ps: p and 1-p are subscript and sorry because I don't have enough condition to attach images 
Thanks you so much!!!!!!

Comment: This isn't really programming. You're looking for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: oh sorry, I am mistaken.I don't know site:math.stackexchange.com.
Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: No prob! Just letting you know why you probably won't get an answer here.